# Asynchronous logging in jQuery

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery

JavaScript code:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  async: true
});

$("a").live('click', function (event) {
 $.get(logsomething-URL);
});
```

ASP.NET code on the logsomething page on the server:

```
Thread.Sleep(10000);
```

When I click a link I have to wait for a response from the server. In this case, I have to wait 10 seconds before I am forwarded to the page I requested.

Is it possible to prevent this?

Answer (score 4):

First you don't need:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    async: true
});
```

because AJAX requests are asynchronous by default (that's what the `A` stands for: asynchronous).

Next you could `return false` from the `click` handler to prevent the default action (which is to follow the href) and in the AJAX `success` handler perform the actual redirect:

```
$('a').live('click', function (event) {
    // store the location to redirect to later in the success callback
    var href = this.href;
    $.get('logsomething-URL', function(result) {
        // Now after the AJAX call successfully returned
        // perform the redirect
        window.location = href;
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: instead of returning false, you can also simply do 'event.preventDefault();' as the first line within your click function.  See more here: http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: @Betard Fooser, yes you can use the `preventDefault` function as well. It is basically the same.

Comment: If I just needed to link, it probably would be a good solution.
I don't think this is a elegant solution to what I had in mind. I need it to work on buttons, links and submits. I can't be sure if a link click actually is a redirect. It could be something else. The subsequent task is unknown.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ought to do it - basically you don't want the link to act like a link:

```
$("a").live('click', function (event) {
    var linkTarget = $(this).attr('href');
    event.preventDefault();
    $.get(logsomething-URL, function(){
         window.location = linkTarget;
    });
});
```

Comment: If I just needed to link, it probably would be a good solution.
I don't think this is a elegant solution to what I had in mind. I need it to work on buttons, links and submits. I can't be sure if a link click actually is a redirect. It could be something else. The subsequent task is unknown.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use `$.get` but instead use `$.ajax` it lets you specify more. If this doesn't work, try have a look at
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'logsomething-URL',
  success: function(data) {    
    alert('Success!');
  },
  global: false
});
```

Comment: And yeah, event.preventDefault() is used to stop the click event from propaganding up, but you mentioned that you do need that. If you could sum up all events on the button/link to one call, then you could control the order of the 'events'